# Pthread + Visual Studio 2013 Compile Error

Tags: c++, pthreads, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with pthread.h and multithreading with c++ and Visual Studio 2013.
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS     1

void *PrintHello(void *)
{

    cout << "Hello World! Thread ID, ";
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL,PrintHello, NULL);
    if (rc){
        cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

When I try to run this

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__pthread_create referenced in function _main    
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I get these errors. But I could not find a way to solve my problem. I need your help.

Comment: do you link properly?

Comment: Yes I linked pthreadVC2.lib

Comment: I don't know to compile on VS for pthread, but it is a linking error (Captain Obvious, I know).

Comment: Ok thank you, I will focus on linking then I will edit my question if I find the solution myself

Comment: Have you set the additional library paths to point to where pthreadVC2.lib lives?

Comment: I probably did everything true. I see something like this, -pthread must be the compile parametre ?

Comment: I think it is not possible to implement phread on visual c++, it is sad.

Comment: The pthread library isn't part of Visual Studio.  It has to be downloaded separately.  It will only link if the library exists.  It must know where to find the library (Additional Library Paths).  Have you downloaded it from ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/dll-latest

Comment: Instructions here : http://web.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/pthread.html

Comment: 1.) Is there a specific reason you are using pthreads on Windows instead of WinAPI? (portability I'm sure, but curious), and 2.) Is there a specific reason you are trying to use pthreads in VS vs. Cygwin/MinGW? You could potentially us the VS IDE and then MinGW/g++ to build as an alternative?

Answer (score 4):

I used the link provided by [Oakdale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2759604/oakdale).

http://web.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/pthread.html

Minor changes for **Visual Studios 2013 Ultimate on a Windows 7 x64**.

Here is the source I used: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w/?source=typ_redirect

This contains a pre-compiled version of pthreads. Use the x86 directories (i.e. /bin, /lib, /include to pull the .dll, libs, and .h.

There are additional .dll, libs and .h that should be added to the VS2013 directories.

### To include pthreads into your VS2013 project:

1. right-click on your project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Additional Include Directories > Add "-lpthread"
2. from the same "Project" Properties Pages > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Add

   - pthreadVC2.lib
   - pthreadVCE2.lib
   - pthreadVSE2.lib

I was able to compile your example above and execute with debug. I got this on the first shot so I may have missed something for other environments. Please post any continued issues.